# how can I solve this error StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: UnableToConnect on redisaec.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have using Regis cache in my project after running the project I have got this error, I cannot find any solution for this problem.

**here is my controller code**

```
public ActionResult Create(Guid orgId, Guid? workflowId, Guid? directoryId)
        {
            IDatabase cache = CacheExtensions.Connection.GetDatabase();

            var processFlowData = this.db.Workflows.Find(workflowId);
            List<WorkflowNode> nodeListBeforeUpdate = null;
            List<WorkflowLink> linkListBeforeUpdate = null;
            if (processFlowData != null)
            {
                nodeListBeforeUpdate = processFlowData.WorkflowNodes.ToList();
                linkListBeforeUpdate = processFlowData.WorkflowLinks.ToList();
                ViewBag.oldNodeList = nodeListBeforeUpdate.Count();
                ViewBag.oldLinkList = linkListBeforeUpdate.Count();
            }
            //var workflowData = this.DatabaseFactory.ProcessFlowUtils.GetWorkflowData(workflowId.GetValueOrDefault());
            var appuser = this.GetDefaultUser();
            ViewBag.AppuserName = appuser.AppUserFullName;
            ViewBag.DirectoryId = directoryId;
            ViewBag.OrgId = orgId;
            ViewBag.IsNew = !workflowId.HasValue;
            if (!workflowId.HasValue)
            {
                workflowId = Guid.NewGuid();
                ViewBag.IsAgentExists = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Considering single deployment
                SetSubscriptionStatus(orgId);
                var agentIdentification = this.DatabaseFactory.AgentUtils.GetDeploymentAgentItem(workflowId, orgId);
                ViewBag.AgentIdentificationGuid = agentIdentification.AgentIdentificationGuid;
                ViewBag.DeploymentStatus = agentIdentification.DeployStatus ?? 1;
                ViewBag.CanExecute = agentIdentification.canExecute;

                if (agentIdentification != null && agentIdentification.AgentDeploymentId != Guid.Empty)
                {
                    var isAgentExists = this.DatabaseFactory.ProcessFlowUtils.IsAgentExist(agentIdentification.AgentIdentificationGuid, orgId);
                    ViewBag.IsAgentExists = isAgentExists;
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.IsAgentExists = false;
                }
            }
           
            ViewBag.WorkFlowId = workflowId;
            cache.Set("WorkflowID", workflowId, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            return View();
        }
```

**here is the cache extension code.**

```
public static class CacheExtensions
    {
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> redisConnection = GetNewRedisConnection();
        public static LazyThreadSafetyMode LazyThreadSafetyMode = LazyThreadSafetyMode.None;
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> GetNewRedisConnection()
        {
            return new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
            {
                return ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisConnection"]).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }, LazyThreadSafetyMode);
        }

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return redisConnection.Value;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                    redisConnection = GetNewRedisConnection();
            }
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this IDatabase cache, string key)
        {
            return Deserialize<T>(cache.StringGet(key));
        }

        public static object Get(this IDatabase cache, string key)
        {
            return Deserialize<object>(cache.StringGet(key));
        }

        public static byte[] GetBytes(this IDatabase cache, string key)
        {
            return cache.StringGet(key);
        }
        public static void Set(this IDatabase cache, string key, object value)
        {
            int convertedVal;
            var expTimeSpan = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisExpiryTime"];
            bool isNumerical = int.TryParse(expTimeSpan, out convertedVal);
            cache.StringSet(key, Serialize(value),
                isNumerical == true ? TimeSpan.FromHours(convertedVal) : TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        }
        public static void SetByteArray(this IDatabase cache, string key, byte[] value)
        {
            int convertedVal;
            var expTimeSpan = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisExpiryTime"];
            bool isNumerical = int.TryParse(expTimeSpan, out convertedVal);
            cache.StringSet(key, Serialize(value),
                isNumerical == true ? TimeSpan.FromHours(convertedVal) : TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        }
        public static void Set(this IDatabase cache, string key, object value, TimeSpan timeToLive)
        {
            cache.StringSet(key, Serialize(value), timeToLive);
        }
        static byte[] Serialize(object o)
        {
            if (o == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, o);
                byte[] objectDataAsStream = memoryStream.ToArray();
                return objectDataAsStream;
            }
        }

        static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] stream)
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            if (stream == null)
                return default(T);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(stream))
            {
                T result = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

**full details of issues is:** UnableToConnect on redisaec.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.2.50.36290
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: UnableToConnect on redisaec.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.2.50.36290

Comment: Please help me with these issues.

Comment: Can you telnet into that server? Try `telnet redisaec.redis.cache.windows.net 6380` (install `telnet` if you don't already have it)

Comment: @abdusco how can I add telnet into server? can you please tell me

Comment: Did you check if you already have it? I don't know what server you have, you can search to find out how to install it.

Comment: @abdusco it already exists. I have using AZURE server

Comment: Can you ping it? Because `redisaec.redis.cache.windows.net` (which I assume is not obfuscated) doesn't resolve for me.

Comment: @abdusco it also doesn't resolved for me.

Comment: Well, then you have a typo in the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the format of `RedisConnection` in your peoject.

It should be like below:

```
yourredisname.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=13l***yt8=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,allowAdmin=true
```

I saw your add asp.net core tag. And previous I have created a sample code about azure cache for redis which use `Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>`. And you can refer it or [download it from github](https://github.com/Jason446620/redis-mvc-core-master/tree/b363aac43b7d4ecfbb0a846b34854ca235e412ba).

[image]

[image]

---

## If you still have problems, you need to check `Firewall` or `Access keys` on portal.